# How can I find Multivariate normal distribution original paper? And other nature-revealing articles by the way

Tags: probability, reference-request, normal-distribution

I want to see how Gauss get this distribution function representation. I want to understand deeper of Multivariate normal distribution.

I tried but failed to search the original paper of Gauss showing the whole process of inventing this function. Please help!

Thanks to Gerry Myerson, I realize it's written in latin. But is there an English version?

And I want to see more articles revealing the nature of the Multivariate normal distribution. Can you recommend some?

Comment: You might wish to expand on what you mean by *the nature of the multivariate normal distribution*.

Comment: How good is your Latin? That's the language in which Gauss generally wrote his papers.

Comment: So I see.. I never thought it's written in latin. But is there an english version? I think someone should have translated it.